# Is there any advantage in organizing methods and functions in objects besides organization?

Tags: javascript, object, coding-style

Is there any advantage in organizing objects, variables and functions inside objects in (specifically) Javascript?

E.g., suppose you are coding a game and you have the following functions `loadImages(), loadMusic(), loadBackgrounds(), checkIfEnemiesAreDead(), populateEnemiesArray(), checkIfPlayerIsDead(), givePlayerUpgrade().`

What are the advantages of creating objects, say, a `loader` object, an `enemy` object and a `player` object to hold all these methods, compared to simply vertically grouping them together? I see some programmers creating objects to store them, and others just grouping them close to each other based on what it does. Does it make the code that much cleaner? Also, what kind of problems can not storing (or storing) them in objects could possibly cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious advantage would be the prototype inheritance model. An object can inherit methods from its prototype or it can override its prototype properties. This allows for code reuse.

The most important feature of objects in my opinion, is that fact that each object basically acts as a namespace for a set of properties. This way you can have multiple properties with the same name across different objects.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using objects to store data is a good things because that organizes your code by chunking. The `loadImages()`and `loadBackground()` function are for graphics, so you can use `Graphics.loadImages()` and `Graphics.loadBackground()`, now they look organized. But it's up to you, how you want to organize your code. It doesn't really effect the way your application will work. However, organized code is always easy to manage and that is why I prefer this.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it provides a great advantage in letting the code be testable. The more you separate a code into logic units the better you can write tests for the specific units by mocking the others and see if they fail with their own inner logic.